# Meaning of "=" in type declaration in Hashkell

Tags: haskell

As I learn Haskell, I can't help but try to understand everything from a formal point of view. After all this is the theoretical coherence I came to look for as a Scala Programmer.

One thing that does compute well in my mind, is fitting the meaning of type declaration in the overraching theory of lambda calculus and everything is an expression. Yes there is Binding, but Binding does not work with type declaration either.

Example

```
data DataType a = Data a | Datum
```

**Question:**

1. What is the meaning of `=` here? If it was the declaration of a function, then on the rhs we would get an expression reducible to an irreducible value or another expression (i.e. returning a function). This is not what we have above.

**My confusion**

We have a type function in `DataType a`, and Data Constructor a.k.a Value Constructor in `Data a` and `Datum`. Clearly a type is not equal to a value, one is at the term level and the other at the type level. Not the same space at all. However it might work to follow the pronunciation provided here https://wiki.haskell.org/Pronunciation. `=` is pronounced `is`. As in a DataType is those values. But that is a stretch. because it is not the same semantic as for a function declaration. Hence I'm puzzled. A Type Level function equal a value level function makes no sense to me.

**My question reformulated differently so to explain what i am looking for**

So in a sense, I would like to understand the semantic of a data declaration and where does it fit in everything is an expression (Haskell theoretical framework) ?

2. Clarifying the difference with Binding. Generally speaking, when talking about binding, can we say it is an expression of type Unit ? Otherwise, what is it, and what is the type of it, and where does it fit in lambda calculus or whatever we should call the theoretical framework that backs Haskell ?

Comment: I voted to close because this question needs more focus.

Comment: How so, i am just asking the meaning of `=`, how is that not focused ? what would have me change there ? Is it the stretch at the end ? do you want me to split the question. I'm learning the language and trying to understand the formal semantic, and specifically the meaning of equal ? If that is not focus i don't know what is ?]

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place to ask one question at a time. You have many questions here. This is not a discussion forum. r/haskell maybe?

Comment: ok i will split it

Comment: Can you shorten this question to the main points, only? As it is, it's impossible to answer without writing several pages. Anyway, Scala's `sealed trait`s and related `case class`es,  are close enough to Haskell's ADTs.

Comment: This is not the answer i am looking for and that is why I took the time to explain myself in details, because it is quite sublte. I'm interested in the foundation of haskell, that is why i am learning it. I know well how to build ADT in scala, but that is not what i am after here.

Comment: I have simplified the question there is clearly  1 point here, i just explain where i am in understanding it right now, so someone can answer to me from the perspective of where i am stuck at. I hope this is concise enough now, could you unclose it ?

Comment: `DataType a = Data a | Data a` isn't valid Haskell in the first place. Please provide an *actual* example. If you have something like `data Foo a = Data1 a | Data2 a`, the equal sign is simply part of the syntax: it defines a new type constructor named `Foo` that takes a single type argument, as well as a pair of data constructors of type `a -> Foo a`.

Comment: @chepner I never wrote what you wrote, please read my definition, it is clearly `DataType a = Data a | Datum `  two different data constructor `Data a` and `Datum`. Where do you get `DataType a = Data a | Data a ` from ?

Comment: My question is clearly about the `semantic`, not the `syntax`. More specifically the formal semantic of equal.  If you want an example of what i am talking about you can find it here https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html. But it is tough to diggest and i suspect, that given the reputation of the haskell comunity be friendly, that someone, would be ok to help a wonderer graph the logic behind things :)

Comment: Typo on my part, but the LHS it what is invalid in Haskell. A function name must start with a lowercase letter, and a type declaration must start with one of the keywords `data`, `type`, or `newtype`. If you are only missing the keyword, my point stands: `=` is just part of the syntax, not an operator in an expression that you can decompose.

Comment: Thanks, i omitted the data keyword .... was implicit :)

Comment: That `=` simply isn't semantic. It's somewhat historical. These days, GADT syntax seems more sensible, representing the addition of particular axioms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest answer here is that `=` doesn’t have any one meaning in particular — it is simply the syntax which the Haskell designers decided to use for data types. There is no particular relationship between the `=` used in function definitions and the `=` used in ADT definitions; both constructions are used to declare something on the LHS using some sort of specification on the RHS, but that’s about it. The two constructions have more differences than similarities.

As it happens, modern Haskell doesn’t necessarily require the use of `=` when defining an ADT. The `GADTSyntax` and `GADTs` GHCI language extensions enable ‘GADT syntax’, which is an alternate method to define ADTs. It looks like this:

```
data DataType a where
    Data :: a -> DataType a
    Datum :: DataType a
```

This illustrates that the use of `=` is not necessarily a mandatory part of type declarations: it is simply one convention amongst many.

(As to *why* the Haskell designers chose to use the convention with `=`, I’m not entirely sure. Possibly it might have been by analogy with type synonyms, like `type Synonym = Maybe Int`, in which `=` *does* have similarities to its use in function definitions, in that the RHS expresses a type which is then assigned the name on the LHS.)

Comment: That syntax goes back to ML, at least, when a lot of this type stuff was still rather new.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you are a Scala programmer, here is what `DataType` might look like in Scala:

```scala
sealed trait DataType[+A]
case class Data[A](a: A) extends DataType[A]
object Datum extends DataType[Nothing]
```

I read your Haskell code as "A `DataType a` can be either a `Data a` or `Datum`". `DataType` is a type constructor, whereas `Data` is a value constructor and `Datum` is a value. You can think of `Data` as a function `Data :: a -> DataType a`, and `Datum` as something like `Datum :: forall a. DataType a` (imagine the names were lowercase). The RHS tells you which functions you can use to get a value of type LHS.

Comment: I have been defining AGDT with Scala for a while now. So in fact, me coming, to Haskell is really to get to the bottom of what i am doing in Scala, really understand the all thing, because it feels like it is not native to it. Since i start learning haskell things make much more sense. And thanks for your answer ! This helped ```Datum :: forall a. DataType a```

Comment: @MaatDeamon Scala 3 can express this [much more nicely](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rhCIaYGFTBWDIVQX1fKo5w), in a more "native" way.

Comment: @MaatDeamon What kind of blog? [Here's](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/introduction-to-haskell/2-algebraic-data-types) an article about ADTs, if that helps.

Comment: I meant scala 3 as u suggested above. However that is good too :) thanks

Comment: @MaatDeamon Oh, I see. [Here's](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/adts.html) the documentation on ADTs (and above that is documentation on plain enums)